# Calling a Python Function Without Entering a New Input

Tags: python, list, function

I am writing a program that takes an input and turns it into a list of integers, then outputting the minimum and maximum number in the list. When I call the function that turns the input into a list it asks for a new input. How can I fix this so the original input is stored?

```
def getList():
    user_input = input()
    newlist = user_input.split()

    for index in range(len(newlist)):
        newlist[index] = int(newlist[index])
    return newlist

def listMin(aList):
    alist = getList()
    small = alist[0]
    for num in alist:
        if num < small:
            small = num
    return small

def listMax(aList):
    alist = getList()
    large = alist[0]
    for num in alist:
        if num > large:
            large = num
    return large

### main program ###

myList = getList()
print(myList)
print(listMin(myList))
print(listMax(myList))
```

When this is run it asks for a new input for listMin and listMax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `aList` that you already pass as an argument into the functions, not calling `getList()` again.
Simply remove the lines where you call `getList()` unnecessarily:

```
def listMin(aList):
    small = aList[0]
    for num in aList:
        if num < small:
            small = num
    return small

def listMax(aList):
    large = aList[0]
    for num in aList:
        if num > large:
            large = num
    return large
```

Answer (score 0):

It asks you for an input a second time because you are calling `getList()` again when you are inside the `listMin` function.
By deleting `alist = getList()`  you will get rid of that problem, but you should also change all the variable names of `alist` to `aList` or you should change the name of the parameter inside the `listMin` function.